# Express.js Problems with response.json and querying

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I followed a tutorial for a RESTful web app with express:

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/

It showed me how to issue get requests like this:

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('userlist').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});
```

And that makes sense to me. It renders in the jade template, too which is fantastic. Now I'm writing my own app, and it's restful as well. I've come up with the following for my get request

`/budget`

```
router.get('/', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res, next) {

    var db = req.db;
    var user_id = req.user.customData["mongo_id"];
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({'_id' : user_id}, function (err, user_data) {
        res.render('budget', user_data);
    });
});
```

And this renders the template, but I don't think that this will allow me to retrieve JSON from this path later. Is this correct? I have tried putting `res.json(user_data);` inside the collection.find callback, but it literally only renders json on the page, and I cannot figure out why.

I need the JSON data to be 'GETable' because my other REST methods will be asynchronous, and I will need to use `$.getJSON( '/budget', function( data )`

Comment: Have you considered checking headers or query parameters to determine whether you should produce rendered output or plain JSON?

Comment: Forgive this, but what exactly would I be looking for?

Comment: That's up to you. I'm saying you could use one of the two to help differentiate response types. For example you could send JSON only if the `Accept` header contains `application/json` or if there is a query parameter `res=json`.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into those options. Thank you!